# Responsive Mobile and Desktop Friendly 4 Column Footer w Custom Margins w Bootstrap Grids

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid, footer

I'd like to create a 4 column footer that looks nice.  The content for the footers varies in width and I would like to have an equal amount of space between each block of text in the columns.    The only way I know to do this is to add a class to each div and play with the margins until things look right.  I seem to have to add a negative margin to one or more columns so that the spacing is equal between each block of text.  I can get things to look good on large screens, but then when you view the page in a smaller screen, divs overlap and things get wonky.  I'd like the columns to start stacking on top of each other and filling up the entire width of the screen as much as possible.  Here's a jsfiddle and my code that shows what I'm trying to do.  What would you add to this to make it look good on desktops and as many mobile devices as possible?

http://jsfiddle.net/natetg/qhtyL7t8/

```
'<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-bottom footer">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
      <p>columnContentWithLargeWidth</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
      <p>columnContentShort</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
      <p>columnShort</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
      <p>ColumnContentWithLargestWidthAndWantThisAllOnOneLinePlease</p>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>`
```

Comment: I could be completely wrong here, but you state that you want it stacking up, etc, in your actual code (not just what you've posted here and the jsfiddle) do you have spaces in between the words? Right now it's being treated as one word and the browser doesn't know how to handle it. If you add spaces, you get the correct behaviour for bootstrap http://jsfiddle.net/qhtyL7t8/1/

Comment: Imagine a column with a logo, another with an address on three lines, another with a phone number, and the last long column of text with copyright, and links to terms and conditions that just looks better all on one line.  Yes, the words have spaces in a real world example.

Comment: what's wrong with the code you posted it looks fine [ or may be i didn't understand your question :) ] on large desktop you have divided it into 4 columns using col-lg-3.  On small desktop you have used col-md-4 which will make the last box to move to next row and on smaller on ones you have divided it into 2 equal parts. If you want complete block you can use col-xs-12.

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful.  Is there anyway to make the four divs all stack vertically when you get to the smallest screen sizes?  Right now, they overlap when the width gets small.

Answer (score 0):

Try using .container-fluid  and  .row-fluid  instead of container and row.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-bottom footer">
   <div class="container-fluid">
     <div class="row-fluid">
       <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
         <p>columnContentWithLargeWidth</p>
       </div>
       <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
         <p>columnContentShort</p>
       </div>
       <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
         <p>columnShort</p>
       </div>
       <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
         <p>ColumnContentWithLargestWidthAndWantThisAllOnOneLinePlease</p>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no .row-fluid in Bootstrap 3